# fcm receiving two notification

Tags: notifications, push, firebase-cloud-messaging

In fcm receiving two notification.

How to stop Notification tag for android devices?

```
{
  "to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
  "priority" : "normal",
  "notification" : {
    "body" : "This week's edition is now available.",
    "title" : "NewsMagazine.com",
    "icon" : "new"
  },
  "data" : {
    "volume" : "3.21.15",
    "contents" : "http://www.news-magazine.com/world-week/21659772"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change as this way:

```
{
  "to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
  "priority" : "normal",

  "data" : {
    "body" : "This week's edition is now available.",
    "title" : "NewsMagazine.com",
    "icon" : "new",
    "volume" : "3.21.15",
    "contents" : "http://www.news-magazine.com/world-week/21659772"
  }
}
```

Refer:
[notifications_and_data_messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages)

OR

you can call this method to stop notifications processing

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#abortBroadcast()